# converting structures of data, passing HTML around in REACT, [object Object]?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to convert an array of items...

```
const data = [
  {
    title: "T1",
    content: [
      {
        "question": "Q1a",
        "answer": "A1a"
      },
      {
        "question": "Q1b",
        "answer": "A1b"
      }
    ]
},
{
    title: "T2",
    content: [
      {
        "question": "Q2a",
        "answer": "A2a"
      },
      {
        "question": "Q2b",
        "answer": "A2b"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

to the following structure:

```
const data2 = [
  {
    header: "T1",
    body: "<p>Q1a</p><p>A1a</p><p>Q1b</p><p>A1b</p>"
  },{
    header: "etc",
    body: "etc"
  }
]
```

so I can use it my component (I wrote a component called Accordion which accepts a list of items that must be in a particular format and contains HTML. That's probably not a good practice but I don't really have time right now to make things perfect, I just need to get it done so please understand that. Or maybe I'm doing it so wrong and wasting a LOT of time, which actually seems to be the case, so please point that out to me)

Anyway, following my strategy, I constantly get [object Object] when I console.log() stuff that I believe should be a concatenated string of HTML but apparently I'm very wrong.

Any ideas?

```
class App extends Component {

  createMarkup(content) {
    return {__html: content};
  }

  getQAMarkup(item) {
    console.log('getQAMarkup: ', item);

    return (
      <div className="qa-block">
        <p>
          <strong>{ item.question }</strong>
        </p>
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ this.createMarkup(item.answer) }>
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {

    //translate data to accordionItems
    const accordionItems = data.reduce((arr, item) => {

      let header = item.title;
      let body = item.content.reduce((str, item) => {
        str += this.getQAMarkup(item);

        console.log('str: ', str) // object Object?
        return str;
      }, '');

      console.log('body: ', body); // object Object?

      arr.push({
        header: header,
        body: body
      });
      return arr;
    }, []);

    console.log(`accordionItems: ${accordionItems[0].body}`); // object Object?


    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>React Collapse Example</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="App-body">
          {/* <Accordion
            items={ accordionItems }
            openedItemKey={ 0 }
            // onlyOneOpen={ true }
          /> */}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Following Purgatory's suggestion, I did the same with the `accordionItems`:

```
const accordionItems = data.map((item) => {
  return {
    header: item.title,
    body: item.content.map((item) => this.getQAMarkup(item))
  }
});
```

When I passed the `accordionItems` then to my Accordion component it worked like a charm!

But when doing `console.log(accordionItems)` I still got `[object Object]`. Why is that?

Comment: Your data example is invalid it should be `const data = [{title: '...', content: [...]}, {title: '...', content: [...]}]` currently it is `const data = [{title: '...', content: [...], title: '...', content: [...]}]`, please correct and I will try to help.

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing that out. I tweaked it a little bit to make it shorter and made that mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change this section:

```
let body = item.content.reduce((str, item) => {
    str += this.getQAMarkup(item);

    console.log('str: ', str) // object Object?
    return str;
 }, '');
```

Instead of treating the response from `getQAMarkup` as a `string` treat it as an `object`:

```
let body = item.content.map((item) => this.getQAMarkup(item));
//OR
let body = item.content.map(this.getQAMarkup);
```

Now `body` will be an array of elements and you should be able to output it as `{body}` inside your `loop`/`map` in the `Accordion` component.

Comment: Awesome, that's also much simpler than what I was doing!

Comment: @zok thanks, however I should stress that the `html` retruned in `getQAMarkup` should be ported to a component with props for `question` and `answer`. Makes for cleaner code then you could do `item.content.map((item) => <QuestionAnswerComponent question={item.question} answer={item.answer}  />);`, just a suggestion.